# How to write ngxs async observable interpolation in component.ts code instead of html?

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular app's html, I could write this and it would indeed extract from the variable the "title" and show it on screen:

**Below works fine from my component.html**:

```
<input matInput value="{{ (app$ | async).myTitle.match('title: &quot;(.*)&quot;')[1] }}" placeholder="My Title" #title>
```

I want to do some code reuse and insert that to my `component.ts`

**I tried to refactor move the code to component.ts but get error**:

So I tried in my component.ts

```
  getTitle(): Observable<string> {
    return this.app$.map(state => {
        return state.myTitle.match('title: &quot;(.*)&quot;')[1];
      }
    );
  }
```

And then tried to simplify the html to be:

```
value="{{ getTitle | async }}
```

but then I get error:

> InputformComponent.html:7 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function
>   () {
>           return this.app$.map(function (state) {
>               return state.everyBootstrapThemeConfig.match('title: "(.*)"')[1];
>           });
>       }' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
>       at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4232)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._selectStrategy
>   (common.js:4839)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._subscribe
>   (common.js:4829)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe.transform
>   (common.js:4811)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (InputformComponent.html:7)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11914)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11307)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11490)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11313)

I'm probably missing how to access the observable and return an observable of the field in `getTitle()`

Comment: Write `this.title$ = this.getTitle()` in component and then use it as `{{ title$ | async }}`

Comment: I had to write `title$ = this.getTitle()` in the component.ts because `this.title$ = this.getTitle()` yielded an error `Module parse failed: The keyword 'private' is reserved`.  After that when I run the code I get:

`errohandling.ts:13 It happens:  TypeError: this.app$.map is not a function
    at InputformComponent.push../src/app/components/inputform/inputform.component.ts.InputformComponent.getTitle (inputform.component.ts:124)
    at new InputformComponent (inputform.component.ts:35)
    at createClass (core.js:10158)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:10033)`

Comment: Can you put up an example on stackblitz?

Comment: there is issue i think it will return `Observable<string[]>` means array of string not only strig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the function object `getTitle` to the async pipe instead of its invocation `getTitle()`.

```
value="{{ getTitle | async }}
```

instead of

```
value="{{ getTitle() | async }}
```

That's why the error message says `InvalidPipeArgument: function` as in "given function is an invalid argument for this pipe."